# Segmentation Fault in trie for a large number of strings

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, tree, segmentation-fault, trie

I was implementing a trie using classes. It contains search and insert function. It works for smaller number of strings, but for larger number of strings it doesn't.

I tried to find the max number of strings or characters that it fails at 240 characters and 67 seperate strings. On the other hand it works for 500 characters single string. Is it because of dynamic allocation or because I haven't made a destructor for my class.

```
class trieNode {
public:
    trieNode* next[26];
    bool isComplete;
};

class TRIE {

    trieNode* root; // Root for every Trie Declared

    // Function to create a TrieNode
    // with initializations
    trieNode* createNode()
    {
        trieNode* temp = new trieNode;
        for (int it = 0; it < 26; it++)
            temp->next[it] == NULL;
        temp->isComplete = false;
        return temp;
    }

public:
    TRIE()
        : root(createNode()){}; // Constructor

    void insert(string s)
    {
        trieNode* ptr = root;

        for (auto it : s) {
            // cout << it;
            if (ptr->next[it - 'a'] == NULL) {
                ptr->next[it - 'a'] = createNode();
            }
            ptr = ptr->next[it - 'a'];
        }

        ptr->isComplete = true; // Mark end of word
    }
};

int main()
{
    TRIE t;
    string A;
    getline(cin, A);

    string temp;
    A += '_';
    int count = 0;
    // Inserting all good words into the Trie
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++) {
        if (A[i] == '_') {
            count++;
            if (!temp.empty())
                t.insert(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
        else
            temp += A[i];
    }
}
```

Strings are seperated by underscore.
It works for this test case 
"qghu_eay_nl_dxfi_cvsc_gg_wk_nqdu_wf_fozv_rtk_pr_p_g_rp_rvys_mwcy_y_c_pev_kef_mz_imkk_svw_r_nzk_cxf_tl_gyp_fad_oo_fxz_co_juv_vabo_gpo_ylf_bnpl_vrvi_ya_yeh_q_qrqp_x_j_loov_o_u_wh_s_cb_coks_zkva_xdkn_yj_h_ixjs_nkk_f_ux_zr_bmnm_q_oke_ly_avcda"

But shows segmentation fault for this

"qghu_eay_nl_dxfi_cvsc_gg_wk_nqdu_wf_fozv_rtk_pr_p_g_rp_rvys_mwcy_y_c_pev_kef_mz_imkk_svw_r_nzk_cxf_tl_gyp_fad_oo_fxz_co_juv_vabo_gpo_ylf_bnpl_vrvi_ya_yeh_q_qrqp_x_j_loov_o_u_wh_s_cb_coks_zkva_xdkn_yj_h_ixjs_nkk_f_ux_zr_bmnm_q_oke_ly_avcdasc"

Forgive any formatting errors. My first question here.

Comment: Instead of `for (int it = 0; it < 26; it++) temp->next[it] == NULL;` you could have a constructor of your `trieNode` class.

Comment: And what did you debugger tell you was the reason for the segfault? Did you run this program in a debugger already. What observations did you make with your debugger?  And if you didn't run this programmer in the debugger yet, why not?

Comment: Use a debugger to isolate the offending line of code.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++) {` I think a range based for loop would be better here.

Comment: I don't see the segfault when trying to debug this in my head. Although if your input was somehow out of range `ptr->next[it - 'a']` could invoke UB. You may want to check if `it` is between `'a'` and `'z'`

Comment: `temp->next[it] == NULL;` is your bug. I did not spot that (even though I quoted that same line above..) but my compiler told me this: ***1>C:\Users\dresc\source\repos\SO_101916716_20190831\SO_101916716_20190831\SO_101916716_20190831.cpp(25,19): warning C4553:  '==': result of expression not used; did you intend '='?*** Note that ==  is comparison. And = is assignment

Comment: Always run your compiler with all warnings on, warnings treated as errors! it is the only way to program in C++ and remain sane. Good catch @drescherjm!

Comment: Oh it was the ==, thanks a lot. I will turn on the warnings